# CMake targets file adds weird suffix to linked libraries

Tags: cmake

I have a project `Foo` that links libraries `curl`, `threads` and `jsoncpp`. I build `Foo` and it generates a `FooTargets.cmake` targets file, that I can use in my project `Bar` to link it (with something like `find_package(Foo REQUIRED)` and then `Foo::Foo`).

Now this `FooTargets.cmake` somehow links `curl` and `threads` in a weird way:

```
INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<LINK_ONLY:CURL::libcurl::@<0x56344f65d140>>;
\$<LINK_ONLY:Threads::Threads::@<0x56344f65d140>>;\$<LINK_ONLY:JsonCpp::JsonCpp>;
```

i.e. it adds this weird `@<0x56344f65d140>`, for some reason.

But then, when configuring project `Bar`, I get the following errors:

```
CMake Error at bar/CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_executable):
  Target "bar" links to target "CURL::libcurl::@<0x55c57ad49530>"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at bar/CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_executable):
  Target "bar" links to target "Threads::Threads::@<0x55c57ad49530>"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Note that when running the same steps on my CI, it seems to just work. Also if I manually edit `FooTargets.cmake` and remove the `@<0x55c57ad49530>`, it works just fine.

Why do they have this `@<0x55c57ad49530>` appended, where e.g. `JsonCpp` does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening with CMake version 3.16.3. Newer versions of CMake don't seem to have that problem, which explains why the CI was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. alternatively I was able to solve it by only having one target_link_libraries (on cmake 3.13). If you ran into the same issue and you are unable to upgrade, try to call target_link_libraries only once for the target.